# Monotonicity Criterion and convergence

Tags: real-analysis

If for all natural numbers $n$,  $y_n\leq y_{n+1}\leq 0\leq x_n\leq x_{n+1}$ and $(x_n +y_n)$ converges to zero then $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge.

Can anyone tell me if my 'proof' of this statement holds? From monotonicity criterion we know that since $y_n$ is increasing and bounded above, it will converge to its supremum (notably $0$). Because of this, using the additivity of limits: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n)=0$. Thus, $x_n$ also converges.

Comment: $\sup y_n$ is not necessarily $0$. Consider, for example, the sequence $(y_n)$ with $y_n=-1$.

Comment: Ah! True. Then how could I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've  made a good start (deducing that $\lim_ny_n\le 0$ exists). Now to finish: $\lim_nx_n=\lim_n(x_n+y_n)-\lim_ny_n$ exists because the two limits being subtracted each exist.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much!